# Spree 2.1 deployment on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, spree

I am trying to deploy an ecomm site I am developing to Heroku.

I am using Rails 4, Spree 2.1 with the Spree_Fancy theme overtop that, S3 for images, and postgres as database in all environments.

The application is working perfectly on my local machine, but when I deployed it to Heroku, the front end breaks. The app runs via Heroku, but there is no styling at all, no theme, nothing. Just plain text and "no products found" message.

I expected there to be no images (since none had yet been uploaded to s3), but there were no products either, even though the db migrations ran.

Any ideas of what I am missing?

Comment: Did you do `heroku run rake db:seed`?

Comment: Yes. I did run that as well. And seemingly it worked. But the front end stuff still a no go.

Comment: The database migrations should not be expected to add products to your application.  The database migrations generally provide the structural changes to the schema.  You'll be expected to add the products through the administration interface.

Answer (score 0):

I've just answered on another thread the same problem scenario. Hope it helps.

[Broken spree_fancy layout on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131009/broken-spree-fancy-layout-on-heroku/21803071#21803071)